# responsive table does not show column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

when you reduce the browser window you will see a different lay out for tables in iphone screen lay out.....

my responsive table code is working fine when column has values....
but when my responsive table does not have column haves it **does not show the corresponding column....**

providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/68yA3/

```
table { 
        width: 100%; 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
    /* Zebra striping */
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
        background: #eee; 
    }
    th { 
        background: #1a4567; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
    td, th { 
        padding: 6px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        text-align: left; 
    }

    /* 
    Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
    This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
    and also iPads specifically.
    */
    @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }

        td:before { 
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: static;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%; 
            padding-right: 10px; 
            white-space: nowrap;
        }


        /*
        Label the data
        */
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "MFG P/N"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "MFG Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Part ID"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Description"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Cost"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Price"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "On Hand"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "On Order"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Allocated"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Shipped"; }
        td:nth-of-type(11):before { content: "Report"; }
        td:nth-of-type(12):before { content: "RMA"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "File"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Add Part"; }
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        body { 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 320px; }
        }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body { 
            width: 495px; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many weird quarks of HTML tables.  When you have no content to put in the cell, just set the content to `&nbsp;`.

Comment: I started to, but your code is pretty long and confusing.  You're on your own on that one, unless someone else comes along.